# Why is this clause unsatisfiable?

Tags: logic, satisfiability

The question says, Which of the following statements apply?

And the answer says this one does but I'm not sure why.

- The clauses {a,b},{a,-b},{-a} are unsatisfiable
- The clauses {a},{-a,b},{-b} are unsatisfiable

Also, why is it not possible to derive the empty clause from {x,y},{-x,-y}?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not possible to derive the empty clause from $\{ x, y \}, \{ \lnot x, \lnot y \}$ ?

Because $\{ x, y \}$ is a [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)), i.e. a *disjunction* : $x \lor y$.

Thus the couple of disjunctions :

> $x \lor y \ $ and $ \ \lnot x \lor \lnot y$

is obviously *satisfiable*; try with a truth assignment $v$ such that :

> $v(x)=$**t**  and  $v(y)=$**f**.

---

If we apply the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) to : $\{ x, y \}, \{ \lnot x, \lnot y \}$, starting, e.g. with $x$ and $\lnot x$ (but the choice is immaterial), what we get is the clause :

> $\{ y, \lnot y \}$

and this is **not** the empty clause. If we "read" it as : $y \lor \lnot y$, it is obvious that it is *satisfiable*.

Comment: Thanks, I applied the same logic to the first part of my question, and my clauses evaluate to true but I thought satisfiable is means true yet the answer states the clauses are unsatisfiable

Comment: @Aceboy1993 - what logic ? Do you have to apply Resolution ? If so, apply the rule to e.g. the first case and derive the *empty clause*, showing thus that it is unsatisfiable. Of course it is; with the clause $\lnot a$, the only possible assignment is $v(a)=f$ ; but then, there is no way to satisfy **both** $\{ a,b \}$ and $\{ a, \lnot b \}$.